# sbt-osgi Release Repository?

Tags: sbt, sbt-osgi

I'm trying to find the release repo for sbt-osgi.  It seems that it does not exist via http://search.maven.org, http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/webapp/search/artifact/?1&q=sbt-osgi or https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/.  It does appear that the artifacts existed in these repos in the past, but no longer.

Any ideas? https://github.com/sbt/sbt-osgi doesn't say that this needs to be installed locally from source.  Is there new magic in SBT I am not familiar with since the last time I used it (it's been a while)?

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see, all plugins were moved to http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases